# Datagridview with query in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have 2 tables in MySql (privacy , lawsuit_under_500) ,
In privacy i have 2 columns (id , nameofcase ) ,
In lawsuit_under_500 4 columns(id,nameofcase,priceone,pricetwo) ,
I make a form with a datagridview and i want to execute this query :

```
select  privacy.id,lawsuit_under_500.id,privacy.nameofcase, lawsuit_under_500.priceone, lawsuit_under_500.pricetwo
From privacy inner join lawsuit_under_500
where  lawsuit_under_500.id=5 and privacy.id=1 || lawsuit_under_500.id=1 and privacy.id=2  || lawsuit_under_500.id=10 and privacy.id=3
ORDER BY privacy.id
```

In the form i have:

```
  public Form55()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form55_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

I have put the tables in my DataSet but I cant figure out how to make it. I tried  to make privacyBindingSourse in the datagridview and i added manually 2 buttons for priceone and pricetwo put i cant put the query so i can get the information. 
Any ideas/help how to make it ?

**BEFORE YOU ANSWER IF YOU HAVE ANY QUESTION PLEASE ASK ME**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it with this way

```
 private void Form56_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            try
            {
                MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection("MY CONNECTION");

                cnn.Open();
                // - DEBUG 
                // MessageBox.Show("Connection successful!"); 
                MySqlDataAdapter MyDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                MyDA.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("MY QUERY", cnn);
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                MyDA.Fill(table);

                BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
                bSource.DataSource = table;

                dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;

            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                Close();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Your MY SQL connection");
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Your Mysql query");
MySqlDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();

gridview1.datasource=dr;
gridview1.databind();

// try this also

connectionString = "Your Connection";

connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
{
    mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("Your Query", connection);
    DataSet DS = new DataSet();
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];

    //close connection
    this.CloseConnection();
}
```

Comment: where i put this? in form55_Load?

Comment: yes.if you want to  load the data grid on a button click you can use a buttonClick event as well.

Comment: 2 last lines in your code is wrong. it should be dataGridView1 . but now is wrong the datasource and the databind

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: Is Your Application ASP.Net one?

Comment: gridview1 does not exist because is dataGridView1, when i change that the databind says " 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'databind' and no extension method 'databind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) "

Comment: And the datasource says " 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'datasource' and no extension method 'datasource' accepting a first argument of type System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: gridviewi or dataGridView1 is only the name property.

Comment: try this code   
    string connectionString;
    connectionString = "Your Connection";
 
    connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
 
    if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
    
        mySqlDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("Your query", connection);
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
 
        //close connection
        this.CloseConnection();

Comment: The name 'connection' does not exist in the current context , The name 'connectionString' does not exist in the current context ,  does not contain a definition for 'OpenConnection' and no extension method 'OpenConnection' accepting a first argument of type  could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Your first answer was better. But we need to fix the 2 last lines

Comment: i change it to  "dataGridView1.DataSource = dr;" and is ok now, and i am getting an error on "dataGridView1.databind(); " 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'databind' and no extension method 'databind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: In my second code block(after //Try This also) connectionString is a String Type variable. you have to  declare it in your code. connection is  an object of the class MySqlConnection. you  have to  declare it  as MySqlConnection connection=new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

Comment: remove the line gridview1.databind(); and see.

Comment: correct it shows me empty datagridview. the databind() is not working on winforms applications

Comment: Yes, That's why i asked is Your application is ASP.net ?

Answer (score 0):

```
       static  public SqlCeConnection OpenSQL()
    {
        SqlCeConnection cncount = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = " + Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + @"\Database.sdf; Password =''");
        return cncount;
    }

    static  public DataTable  DoSelect( string strSQL)
    {
        SqlCeConnection cn = OpenSQL();

        DataTable dtRetValue = new DataTable();

        using (SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter())
        {
            using (SqlCeCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;

                if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    cn.Open();
                }

                try
                {
                    //using (SqlCeDataReader reader = da.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    SqlCeDataReader metsDr = da.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    dtRetValue.Load(metsDr);


                    return dtRetValue;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error - DoSelect", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Insert in Button

```
        string sql1 = "YOURE QUERY ";
        DataTable dt1 = SQLcode.DoSelect(sql1);
        dgvcompany.DataSource = dt1;
```